# Return an array of what GridLayout contains

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, grid-layout

I have a JPanel with GridLayout of JButtons. There is a number of operations happening inside this panel, where buttons get enabled and disabled a few times. Now I am creating some JUnit tests and in the end need to check that all JButtons are disabled.

Is there a method, which would allow me to return a collection of JButtons from the GridLayout or at least a JButton from certain position so that I can loop through it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply se `JPanel.getComponents` and the result will contain all components in the `JPanel`.

Comment: Did you know that you can click the checkmark below the upvoting section to accept an answer? That's what it's for.

Comment: Nope, I didn't. Will do from now on. =)